# How do I pass cl::Buffer object between host c++ functions?

Tags: c++, opencl

I am using OpenCL with the C++ wrappers, using the GPU for heavy computations.

Data is in cl::Buffer objects, e.g.

```
std::vector<float> host_z_vec(100, 0.0f);
cl::Buffer device_z_vec;
device_z_vec = cl::Buffer(*context_ptr,
                          CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, 
                          sizeof(float)*host_z_vec.size(),   
                          &host_z_vec.at(0),
                          &status);
```

How should I pass the cl::Buffer object, device_z_vec, between host c++ functions?  - I do not want to make copies of device_z_vec, merely pass it around.

```
void run_on_gpu(cl::Buffer device_z_vec){ ... }
```

or

```
void run_on_gpu(const cl::Buffer& device_z_vec){ ... }
```

?

And is this ok?

```
class StoreBuffer{
    cl::Buffer device_z_vec;
public:
    cl::Buffer provide_access_to_device_z_vec(){ return device_z_vec; };
}
```

or should I be passing a pointer to the cl::Buffer object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing a `cl::Buffer` to a function by value or storing it as a class member are both fine. The copy constructor for the `cl::Buffer` class simply increments the reference count of the underlying OpenCL allocation (via `clRetainMemObject`). The same is true for all of the other OpenCL object classes in `cl.hpp`.